# How to detect edge of the document using GPUImage

Tags: ios, iphone, gpuimage

I am creating an app that detect the edge of document using the `Open-CV framework` but result is not great.

Than i came to this project `GPUImage`. I am don't know anything about this project can anyone suggest me how to detect edge using `GPUImage`. Code or tutorial will be really helpful.

Comment: When you say "edge of a document" do you mean an image / video stream?

Comment: @michaels i means from image.

Comment: I want to create scanner app but i coudnt find the Perfect Edge of document from image. i am using code from this project. If any one has improved it than please share the code if possible. https://github.com/mmackh/MAImagePickerController-of-InstaPDF

Comment: I know that GPUImage offers image filtering based on edge detection (i.e. you can change the look of the image), but I'm not sure it provides edge detection in the form of returning a list of edges

Answer (score 5):

**OpenCV** is a computer vision library, that does do feature detection. When used properly it can find edges and tell your application where in the image they are. Based on your question this appears to be what you need.

**GPUImage** is an image *filtering* library. It applies effects to images. It has several filters that use edge detection, but it will not tell you where those edges are. It applies the filter to the image and that is it.

You should stick with OpenCV. If you are having problems getting the feature detection results you need, that would be a different question to ask.

Comment: GPUImage library is not complete, but is being done as an OpenGL ES implementation of OpenCV.  Looking at GPUImageParallelCoordinateLineTransformFilter should give you some insight of how to get straight lines good enough for a document.  Specifically look for the block that returns the lines.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure you could achieve this with GPUImage. For instance take a look at the [FilterShowcase](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/tree/master/examples/iOS/FilterShowcase)'s "Harris Corner Detection":

[image]

In the underlying [class](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/8d39590de65824efef8e116516ca1d2e3419b20f/framework/Source/GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter.m#L21) you have this code from where it seems you could pull coordinates:

```
NSString *const kGPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFragmentShaderString = SHADER_STRING
( 
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
 uniform lowp float sensitivity;

 const mediump float harrisConstant = 0.04;

 void main()
 {
     mediump vec3 derivativeElements = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate).rgb;

     mediump float derivativeSum = derivativeElements.x + derivativeElements.y;

     mediump float zElement = (derivativeElements.z * 2.0) - 1.0;

     // R = Ix^2 * Iy^2 - Ixy * Ixy - k * (Ix^2 + Iy^2)^2
     mediump float cornerness = derivativeElements.x * derivativeElements.y - (zElement * zElement) - harrisConstant * derivativeSum * derivativeSum;

     gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(cornerness * sensitivity), 1.0);
 }
);
```

If not this one, there are many filters there that you could give a try.